# Relay's consensus data scrubbed for inbound connections

Tags: relays

Since I began running a relay several months ago, I'd occasionally see, using nyx, a recurring inbound connection from one particular Authority, along with its nickname, IP address, and flags. It would stay connected for just a few minutes each time I noticed it. Nothing odd about that. Authorities have been the only inbound connections I've seen. Yesterday, however, for the first time that I've noticed, inbound connections began showing up frequently that show no IP address or other data:

```
address: <scrubbed>:39384
locale: ?? 
No consensus data found
```

Should I be concerned? Why would an Authority, if that is what they are, hide information?

Answer (score 1):

A relay should see many incoming connections from other relays and clients (if your relay has the guard flag). If in the past your relay was not receiving incoming connections, that suggests a configuration or firewall problem.

These connections are not hiding their IP addresses. Rather it is Nyx that hides the IP addresses if they are not in the consensus. This is to protect the privacy of the people who use your relay.

Comment: Daily this relay has several dozen unique clients, a few less circuits for outgoing connections, and a few GB of upload/download activity. My ORPort is reachable from the outside. Would that be so if there was a firewall issue? I had always assumed that it was being used. Nothing has changed with my configurations. Just wondering why non-consensus incoming connections have just started.

Comment: Can you post the fingerprint of your relay? And I'm not sure what you're saying, how did it have several dozen clients but no incoming connections (other than the one authority)?

Comment: It is a bridge relay, if that's a factor. Are bridge fingerprints public?

Comment: Ah they're usually published to the authorities but not public. This would probably explain why you weren't seeing traffic before, because it can often take a while for the bridge to be distributed to users.